# Некорректная обработка даты при построении графиков pandas + matplotlib 2.0.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь построить график по точкам: по оси абсцисс - время, по оси ординат - какие-либо значения. Время преобразую из timestamp unix time в нс. График строится, но граничные значения какие-то странные.

Исходные данные:

```
            timestamp  Value, %
0 2017-04-14 22:00:00      4.96
1 2017-04-14 23:00:00      5.83
2 2017-04-15 00:00:00     10.96
3 2017-04-15 01:00:00      0.03
4 2017-04-15 02:00:00      0.02
5 2017-04-15 03:00:00      0.14
6 2017-04-15 04:00:00      0.30
7 2017-04-15 05:00:00      1.55
8 2017-04-15 06:00:00      2.14
9 2017-04-15 07:00:00      2.74
```

Код:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')  # Красивые графики
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 3 )  # Размер картинок
columns = ['timestamp', 'Value, %']
dataset = [
(1492207200000, 4.96), 
(1492210800000, 5.83), 
(1492214400000, 10.96), 
(1492218000000, 0.03), 
(1492221600000, 0.02), 
(1492225200000, 0.14), 
(1492228800000, 0.3), 
(1492232400000, 1.55), 
(1492236000000, 2.14), 
(1492239600000, 2.74)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=columns)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df.plot(x='timestamp', style='.-')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y %H:%M'))
print(df)
plt.show()
```

График:

[image: График 1]
При этом стоит сделать хотя бы одно значение времени не кратное часу (например, прибавить к первому времени 1 нс или поменять порядок местами), так сразу график начинает строиться нормально. Например:

```
dataset = [
(1492207200001, 4.96), 
(1492210800000, 5.83), 
(1492214400000, 10.96), 
(1492218000000, 0.03), 
(1492221600000, 0.02), 
(1492225200000, 0.14), 
(1492228800000, 0.3), 
(1492232400000, 1.55), 
(1492236000000, 2.14), 
(1492239600000, 2.74)]
```

График:

[image: График 2]

Я вот пытаюсь понять: это какой-то глюк matplotlib или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Unix время - это 10 символов (секунды), у вас их 13 (миллисекунды). Поделите на 1000 и проверьте результат. Никаких наносекунд, конечно же нету у вас.

Comment: Да, простите, я имел ввиду мс, там в функции стоит атрибут соответствующий unit='ms'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Pandas пытается "навести красоту". Для этого используется функция [format_dateaxis()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_timeseries.py#L296), которая использует специальные классы: [TimeSeries_DateLocator](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_converter.py#L851), [TimeSeries_DateFormatter](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_converter.py#L933)

В вашем DataFrame все даты имеют (расположены) одинаковый интервал - один час. Когда вы "нарушаете" это правило Pandas уже не может так красиво сгрупировать время, поэтому выводятся все значения

Пример:

```
In [145]: df.loc[10] = [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-15 09:00'), 3]

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
             timestamp  Value, %
0  2017-04-14 22:00:00      4.96
1  2017-04-14 23:00:00      5.83
2  2017-04-15 00:00:00     10.96
3  2017-04-15 01:00:00      0.03
4  2017-04-15 02:00:00      0.02
5  2017-04-15 03:00:00      0.14
6  2017-04-15 04:00:00      0.30
7  2017-04-15 05:00:00      1.55
8  2017-04-15 06:00:00      2.14
9  2017-04-15 07:00:00      2.74
10 2017-04-15 09:00:00      3.00  # ВНИМАНИЕ: мы "нарушили" интервал в 1 час !!!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У нас сразу изменилась даже "плотность" `x-ticks` по сравнению с DF (с регулярным интервалом):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Варианты решения проблемы:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/5741205

http://brenda.moon.net.au/2012/10/18/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135182/5741205

Comment: Вот оно что... Спасибо за ответ. Пока как временное решение я добавляю 1 мс к дате и это работает.